# How to configure haproxy to run a Pluto notebook server with reverse proxy

Tags: julia, haproxy, pluto

I have tried to use a backend configuration on haproxy.cfg as:

```
backend be_pluto
  acl https ssl_fc
  http-request set-uri http://localhost/?%[query] if https
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-For %[src]
  server pluto 127.0.0.1:1234
```

And it partially works, but when i go to a browser Haproxy 2.5 is not serving CSS and notebook is not working...

Could you please advice on what is missing?